# How to link 2 input fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Is there a way to link 2 inputs to each other? For example, I have this code:

```
<td><input type="radio" name="server1" required="true" value="Yes" checked />Yes</input><input type="radio" name="server1" required="true" value="No" />No</input></td>
```

I need to add hidden input (or another radio button) that inserts 1 if Yes is selected and -1 if No is selected. (The value in this field will be inserted into different column in MySQL db).

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Use checkbox for Yes/No

Comment: Using a checkbox for Yes/No? Doesn't make sense. It's either Yes OR No. I doubt the OP wants both, therefore a radio button is more appropriate. @Satpal --- Using a checkbox will only let people the choice to choose "both". When somebody asks you if you want a slice of pizza, do you answer Yes/No? ;-) --- That's "IF" you like pizza ;-)

Comment: In my opinion, the OP needs to use a radio button for Yes/No choices. He/she can't have both. @Satpal

Comment: For a confirmation, a checkbox is ok, for a specific answer, either "yes" or "no", just like in "male" or "female", radios are more appropriate.

Comment: Just like you @adeneo said. Makes sense, a person can be male `or` female, not `and`; however a `transvestite` would fall into that category ;-) It's not like an animal having two sexes/genders, although there are some, who don't come to mind at this very instant, but I could Google it ;-)

Comment: And I would do it like in my answer below, the selected value is sent to the server, so as long as the radios are a group (have the same name) the value of the selected radio is sent to the server, you can figure it out there, or just change the values in the HTML to "1" and "-1".

Comment: That's what I meant to say all along, right? @Satpal (Isn't that what I did say?)

Comment: Fred is correct - I have to use radio buttons - this is for our IT guys to specify if server back up was successful or not. The third field (where I need 1 or -1) is to generate highcharts graph.

Comment: You don't need a third field, you can set the value of the radios to anything, and you can catch it on the serverside and do just about anything with it.

Comment: If nothing is chosen, then using an `else` condition could be used to enter the appropriate data into DB, instead of having a third field as @adeneo mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Your code -as is- will send a field named "server1" to the server with either the value "Yes" or "No", according to what the user selected. You don't need a third field, in PHP yo do:

```
$server1 = isset($_REQUEST["server1"]) && $_REQUEST["server1"]=='Yes' ? 1 : -1;
```

and that's all.